# Close a Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, window, osx-mountain-lion, close-application

I've created a Mac OS X application, and during the development it was fine because I opened it with Xcode.

But now, I try to execute the executable and it's working only the first time, because after close the window, the app persists in memory. And I have to kill it with the activity monitor.

So what should I do to kill the app when I touch the red top left button on the window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quit app when NSWindow closes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941960/quit-app-when-nswindow-closes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)application
{
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the windowWillClose method in your delegate to make it terminate the app.

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSApp terminate:self];
}
```

Comment: Won't that close the program if any window is closed, regardless if it is the last one?

Comment: Yes, the applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed approach is more suitable but the windowWillClose came to my mind because I figured the app in question as a one-window app.